# How to prove that $f(x)x - \int_{0}^{x}{f(t) \,dt} = \int_{f(0)}^{f(x)}{f^{-1}(t) \,dt},$ for all invertible functions.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing, inverse

A while ago, I found that:

$$f(x)x - \int_{0}^{x}{f(t) \,dt} = \int_{f(0)}^{f(x)}{f^{-1}(t) \,dt}.$$

I managed to prove it for a few functions, and I believe that it may be the case for all invertible functions.

However, I would like to be able to prove it for all invertible functions, if, of course, it is true.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions There is a very beautiful way to view this graphically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, then

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x) \,\,dx+\int_c^d f^{-1}(y) \,\,dy &=\int_a^b f(x) \,\,dx+\int_a^b f^{-1}(f(x)) f'(x) \,\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b f(x) \,\,dx+\int_a^b x f'(x) \,\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b \left(f(x)+x f'(x)\right) \,\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b (xf(x))' \,\,dx\\\\
&=bf(b)-af(a)\\\\
&=bd-ac
\end{align}$$

Now, let $a=0$, $b=x$, $c=f(0)$, and $d=f(x)$.

Comment: Ah, so it is true! Thank you!

Comment: @Taylor Yes, it is true. And you're welcome!  My pleasure.